# Enable C11 threads in MSVC 17.8

Tags: c, visual-studio-2022

I was happy to hear that [C11 threads were finally implemented in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.8 Preview 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c11-threads-in-visual-studio-2022-version-17-8-preview-2/).

Unfortunately, while the DLLs are there, I'm unable to find the header anywhere. I installed Visual Studio with the default options for C++ development. I'm using the latest Preview (7)  with Windows 11 SDK 10.0.22621.0.

Does anyone have any clue on how to enable them?

Comment: Probably a bug in the preview. Anyway did you choose "ISO C11 Standard" in "C/C++->Language->C Language Standard" in the project properties?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, I tried all options for standards in both C and C++. Then searched for `threads.h` in the filesystem, with no results. It's strange to make an announcement and then forget to ship what was announced...

Comment: Also doesn't work in the 17.8 non-preview release.

Comment: Still no file in version 17.9.0 Preview 2.1, but workaround available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, just to let everyone know that they are aware of the problem:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missing-threadsh-in-MSVC-178/10514752

**UPDATE** On December 7 2023, they updated the state of the issue to `Fixed - Pending Release`, along with this message:

> A fix for this issue has been internally implemented and is being prepared for release. We’ll update you once it becomes available for download.

**UPDATE**: On December 14 2023, as a workaround, they provided a link to this version of [threads.h](https://aka.ms/dc/file?name=B577b3a1006464e90b10197d5d419526c638381100848159134_threads.h&tid=577b3a1006464e90b10197d5d419526c638381100848159134) which works perfectly.
The file is still missing in Version 17.9.0 Preview 2.1

**UPDATE**: On January 10 2024 the issue was promoted to `Fixed In: Visual Studio 2022 version 17.8.4`. I can confirm that now everything is there as expected.

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr; It seems they *did* implement some C11 threads support, but didn't ship a `threads.h`.

**UPDATE:** Someone from microsoft attached the real `threads.h` in the support thread https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missing-threadsh-in-MSVC-178/10514752

I did some digging, and while they apparently did not ship a `threads.h` header, they did implement part of the C11 standard. I discovered this by writing my own header file, based on `xthreads.h` (the internal C++ thread header). From what I've read, the C++ standard heavily influenced the C version of the threads library, so I assumed the API would be similar.

This is the header file I created, it's not complete, it doesn't have mutexes or conditions in it. But it does have the standard thread functions `thrd_create` and `thrd_join`.

It seems microsoft did not implement `thrd_sleep`, I get "unresolved symbols" if I try to define `thrd_sleep`.

```c
#ifndef _THREADS_H
#define _THREADS_H

#include <time.h>

typedef unsigned int _Thrd_id_t;

struct thrd_t { // thread identifier for Win32
    void* _Hnd; // Win32 HANDLE
    _Thrd_id_t _Id;
};
typedef struct thrd_t thrd_t;

enum thrd_result { 
  thrd_success = 0,
  thrd_nomem = 1,
  thrd_timedout = 2,
  thrd_busy = 3,
  thrd_error = 4
};

/** THIS SECTION IS COPIED FROM GNU LIB C **/
/** Copyright (C) 2018-2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc. **/
typedef int (*thrd_start_t) (void*);
/* Create a new thread executing the function __FUNC.  Arguments for __FUNC
   are passed through __ARG.  If successful, __THR is set to new thread
   identifier.  */
extern int __cdecl thrd_create (thrd_t *__thr, thrd_start_t __func, void *__arg);

/** END GNU LIBC SECTION **/

extern int __cdecl thrd_join(thrd_t, int*);

#endif
```

I used the above header in a test program I have, and it successfully linked to `thrd_create` and `thrd_join` functions, and it does work to create threads!

Comment: `thrd_sleep` is in fact available, using the `threads.h` provided by Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, thrd_sleep is there. I probably had the signature wrong while I was hacking together my header, so I couldn't get it to link. This whole answer is moot since they properly released threads.h

Answer (score 0):

The required threads.h header file is now available at https://aka.ms/dc/file?name=B577b3a1006464e90b10197d5d419526c638381100848159134_threads.h&tid=577b3a1006464e90b10197d5d419526c638381100848159134 (via https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missing-threadsh-in-MSVC-178/10514752#T-N10540847) until the next version of Visual Studio is released which should then have this header file.